# PHP - WebSocket set specific client id

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

I am working with PHP websockets. I am familiar with its basics but I cannot figure out that how can I set a specific ID for user. Now, by default the script sets 1, 2, 3 and so on according to the time the user connected but I want it to set ID which is stored in session. The script I am using is [**this**](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat). I have found the function which generates ID.

```
function wsGetNextClientID() {
    $i = 1; // starts at 1 because 0 is the listen socket
    while (isset($this->wsRead[$i])) $i++;
    return $i;
}
```

Is there any way that I can set a specific one?

Comment: Question that pops to mind is - why? You want to identify your session user with the websocket it was assigned to them?

Comment: @N.B. I have figured that out. Thanks for your response. BTW, I wanted to create private chat.